# Can I have two LOOKUP functions within a single IF function in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to organize  a dashboard of sorts that will place the name of the appropriate owner in a column on the spreadsheet.  The two criteria is the location or US state the item is located in and the type of item it is.  You can see in the image below that I am trying to automate column C depending on the criteria in Column A and B.

[image: Dashboard]

I have the information for each type of item in a separate table in the next sheet.

[image: Tables located in separate sheet]

Is there a better formula to use to route everything to the right person?  I have tried to use the following formula.

```
=IF(L7 = "Boat",(LOOKUP(I7, Mapping!$A$3:$A$67, Mapping!$B$3:$B$67)),
    IF(L7= "House", (LOOKUP(I7, Mapping!$H$3:$H$67)), Mapping!$I$3:$I$67, UNKNOWN))
```

Can you have two LOOKUP formulas in a single IF formula?  Is there an easier formula to use?

I am receive an error when it is a House:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You parentheses doesn't look ok.

```
IF(L7 = "Boat",
(LOOKUP(I7, Mapping!$A$3:$A$67, Mapping!$B$3:$B$67))
, IF(L7= "House",
(LOOKUP(I7, Mapping!$H$3:$H$67, Mapping!$I$3:$I$67))
, UNKNOWN))
```

... quite easy to see if you make things line up.

If Excel asks if you wish to "accept a correction", it most often has got the correction wrong.

There is no real option to make an IF "easier", I believe, unless you can rethink your encoding.
That is: do the same thing in a different manner, that is easier in this regard.

Tip: Make `Mapping!$H$3:$H$67` be a Named range (in "Name manager").

Comment: Parentheses get hard to keep track of, especially extra ones.  Might be easier to follow by eliminating the pair around each LOOKUP.

Comment: @teylyn how can I accept? I don't see that button anywhere.

Comment: As the person who asked a question, you see a gray check mark next to each answer. Select the check mark for the answer that solves your question. See the details in the help page here: http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers